# django forms max_value and step don't work together

Tags: django, django-forms

I've tried several ways. It seems that there isn't one that can get a django form field with max_value and step arguments working.

This is my code:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, TextInput, Select
class NumberInput(TextInput):
    input_type = 'number'

act_ind = forms.DecimalField(required=False, max_value=10, min_value=0,
        widget=NumberInput(attrs={'id': 'form_act_ind', 'type': 'number', 'step': '0.1'}))
```

Step works, but max_value doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after trying many many different ideas, I finally found a solution. 
Using HTML5 max attribute cause Django's wont work:

```
act_ind = forms.FloatField(required=False, max_value=10, min_value=0,
        widget=NumberInput(attrs={'id': 'form_act_ind', 'type': 'number', 'step': '0.1', 'max': '10'}))
```

Hope this is useful to someone.